# Sum the same column different ways

Tags: sql, group-by

here is my table Prod of monthly production report:

```
PruID Prod1 Prod2, ReportDate
001 12.5 32.4 1/1/1999
001 13.0 32.0 2/1/1999
...
002 45.2 32.4 1/1/2004
002 56.3 43.2 2/1/2004
...
```

I want to summarize Prod1 and Prod2, as well as last 12 months of Prod1 & Prod2 by PruID. I wrote 2 separate queries and they are working for each purpose:

Query 1: Summarize prod1 & prod2 by PruID

```
SELECT Prod.PruID, Sum(Prod.Prod1) AS CumProd1, Sum(Prod.Prod2) AS CumProd2
FROM Prod 
GROUP BY Prod.PruID;
```

Query 2: Summarize last 12 month of Prod1 & Prod2 by PruID

```
SELECT PruID, Sum(Prod1) AS Cum12MonProd1, Sum(Prod2) AS Cum12MonProd2
FROM Prod
WHERE Prod.ReportDate > DATEADD('m', -12, now())
GROUP BY PruID;
```

How to combine the 2 queries to one to produce something like this:

```
PruID  CumProd1 CumProd2 Cum12MonProd1 Cum12MonProd2
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to exclude the data that you're filtering out in the second query from the `sum` function for the filtered total.

```
SELECT   prod.pruid,
         SUM (prod.prod1) AS cumprod1,
         SUM (prod.prod2) AS cumprod2,
         SUM (
            CASE
               WHEN prod.reportdate > dateadd ('m', -12, now ()) THEN
                  prod.prod1
               ELSE
                  NULL
            END)
            AS cum12monprod1,
         SUM (
            CASE
               WHEN prod.reportdate > dateadd ('m', -12, now ()) THEN
                  prod.prod2
               ELSE
                  NULL
            END)
            AS cum12monprod2
FROM     prod
GROUP BY prod.pruid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either `JOIN` the two subqueries:

```
SELECT a.PurID, a.CumProd1, a.CumProd2, b.Cum12MonProd1, b.Cum12MonProd2
FROM
(

    SELECT Prod.PruID, Sum(Prod.Prod1) AS CumProd1, Sum(Prod.Prod2) AS CumProd2
    FROM Prod 
    GROUP BY Prod.PruID
) a INNER JOIN
(

    SELECT PruID, Sum(Prod1) AS Cum12MonProd1, Sum(Prod2) AS Cum12MonProd2
    FROM Prod
    WHERE Prod.ReportDate > DATEADD('m', -12, now())
    GROUP BY PruID
) b
ON a.PruID = b.PruID;
```

or use a `CASE` in the second set of sums:

```
SELECT 
    Prod.PruID, 
    Sum(Prod.Prod1) AS CumProd1, 
    Sum(Prod.Prod2) AS CumProd2,
    Sum(CASE WHEN Prod.ReportDate > DATEADD('m', -12, now()) THEN Prod1 ELSE 0) AS Cum12MonProd1,
    Sum(CASE WHEN Prod.ReportDate > DATEADD('m', -12, now()) THEN Prod2 ELSE 0) AS Cum12MonProd2
FROM Prod 
GROUP BY Prod.PruID;
```